# mysql NOT IN not show result

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT * FROM device
WHERE (device_id NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM vehicle)) AND client_id =3
```

this for my query, this query working fine in **phpmyadmin**. but not working mysql workbench **MySql Workbench**.

i'm using **MySql Workbench version 5.7.20**

**device table**

```
device_id  device_name status
 1         OLX          1
 2         AMA          1
```

**vehicle table**

```
id  vehicle_name device_id  status
 1      indica     NULL         1
 2      innov      NULL         2


SELECT * FROM device
WHERE (device_id NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM vehicle)) AND client_id =3
```

USE THIS QUERY IN PhpMyadmin , **i'll get all rows from device table**

BUT Same Query Show Give result

```
device_id device_name  status
```

Comment: A query doesn't return different results based on SQL IDE. you sure you are connected to the same database and table?

Comment: yes this two tables present on same database

Comment: @Tamil Raymond was talking about the connection. Check they are usin the same connection.  Run `SELECT * FROM device` and `SELECT * FROM vehicle` If both connection return same sets your query should have same result.

Comment: `client_id` does not exist in any of the tables. but you used this column in your query! Seems you are really not using same database!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in `device` table column `` doesn't even exist. Also remove unnecessary parentheses. Following query will do.

```
SELECT * FROM device d
WHERE 
    d.device_id NOT IN (SELECT device_id FROM vehicle) as sub_query AND 
    d.status <> 1
```